# Any tools for detecting all the .NET dll's referenced

Tags: .net, utility

I use Antlr tools as follows (on Mono)

```
dmcs  /r:Antlr3.Runtime.dll /r:StringTemplate.dll *.cs /out:Main.exe
```

I reference two dll's, but there is another dll file (antlr.runtime.dll) that is referenced behind the scene. I got this when I have an error just copying two dlls and compile.

Are there any .NET tools to detect what dll's are referenced? For example, if I run 'DETECT Antlr3.Runtime.dll', I get 'antlr.runtime.dll'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or write one using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) ([NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) use this)

### Example using Mono.Cecil

In a new project, reference [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)

```
using System;
using Mono.Cecil;

namespace ReferenceDetector
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var assemblyPath = args[0];
      var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(assemblyPath);
      Console.WriteLine(assemblyDefinition.Name.FullName);
      foreach (AssemblyNameReference reference in assemblyDefinition.MainModule.AssemblyReferences)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + reference.FullName);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? Just compiling your code gives me errors. Thanks.

Comment: @prosseek: I've updated my code to work with the version of Mono.Cecil that i've linked.

Answer (score 3):

Give [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) a go. It has a dependency graph/dependency matrix feature that lets you explore dependencies between DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  (Recursively expand the References node)